# Грамматическая основа. Пример

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор, подлежащее, основа

**Воспитание для величия всегда сложно.**

*Воспитание* - подлежащее, *всегда сложно* - сказуемое? 
Правильно? И вопрос будет какой, не могу определить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение не вполне удачное, но его грамматическая основа прозрачна: *воспитание (подл.) **каково?** сложно (сказ.)*. *Всегда* здесь обстоятельство времени, *для величия* — определение.

Здесь внимание нужно обращать не на вопрос, а скорее на смысл: основная мысль в том, что воспитание — сложный процесс, она и выражается грамматической основой.

Comment: Да, не вполне удачное. "Воспитание для величия" или "сложно для величия"? Оба варианта непонятны.